# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr when making a matrix

Tags: arrays

I am trying to create a matrix acting on a vector but keep getting the error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. I am working using miktex. This strangely works when I type it in stack exchange and I have no idea why this is the case. Can anyone fix this?

```
\begin{center}
$ = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
A_{00}^{00} & A_{01}^{00} & A_{10}^{00} & A_{11}^{00} \\
A_{00}^{00} & A_{01}^{01} & A_{10}^{01} & A_{11}^{01} \\
A_{00}^{011} & A_{01}^{10} & A_{10}^{10} & A_{11}^{10} \\
A_{00}^{11} & A_{01}^{11} & A_{10}^{11} & A_{11}^{11} \\
\end{array}\right 

\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\rho_{00} \\
\rho_{01} \\
\rho_{10} \\
\rho_{11} \\
\end{array}\right]$
\end{center}
```

Comment: If you're using `array` you have to specify as many columns as you use, in this case you're specifying two centred columns (`cc`), but you use 4 columns in the body.

Comment: It might be a good idea to read an introduction to LaTeX which covers at least the basics of maths mode. One viable option for this could be [learnlatex.org](https://www.learnlatex.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Please note that there are several issues with your code.

1. Don't use `\begin{center}$...$\end{center}` for displayed maths, instead use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` or similar constructs.
2. When you're using `array` you have to specify as many columns as you need (or more, that doesn't hurt), so it should be `\begin{array}{cccc}` for your first matrix.
3. If you want to input a matrix, it might be a good idea to use one of the dedicated environments provided by `amsmath` (`\begin{bmatrix}` here) instead of `array`.

Everything put together:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A_{00}^{00} & A_{01}^{00} & A_{10}^{00} & A_{11}^{00} \\
    A_{00}^{00} & A_{01}^{01} & A_{10}^{01} & A_{11}^{01} \\
    A_{00}^{011} & A_{01}^{10} & A_{10}^{10} & A_{11}^{10} \\
    A_{00}^{11} & A_{01}^{11} & A_{10}^{11} & A_{11}^{11} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \rho_{00} \\
    \rho_{01} \\
    \rho_{10} \\
    \rho_{11} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specify the columns in the matrix, then you can use plainTeX `\matrix` macro:

```
$$
  \def\A#1#2#3#4{A_{#1#2}^{#3#4}} \def\r#1#2{\rho_{#1#2}}
  \left[\matrix{
    \A0000    & \A0100 & \A1000 & \A1100 \cr
    \A0000    & \A0101 & \A1001 & \A1101 \cr
    \A000{11} & \A0110 & \A1010 & \A1110 \cr
    \A0011    & \A0111 & \A1011 & \A1111 \cr
  }\right]
  \left[\matrix{
    \r00 \cr \r 01 \cr \r10 \cr \r11 
  }\right]
$$
```